# Is there a way to hide street names (google_maps_flutter)?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I'm working on an app, and want to display a map without street names.

Is there any way to disable the street names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google maps for flutter now has the ability to customise styling of maps. Go to [Google Maps Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/), reduce the road density and generate the JSON.

Copy the generated JSON to your assets folder and specify it in your pubspec.yaml file. If your folder is called assets:

```
flutter:  
  assets:
    - assets/no_street_names.json
```

Now, you just need to use this style in your created maps. It can be achieved by setting map style with map's controller. You can use the following code for reference:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
```

```
GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            rootBundle.loadString('assets/no_street_names.json').then((String mapStyle) {
              controller.setMapStyle(mapStyle);
            });
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score -1):

go to https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ and make your own style
you can set :
Roads
Landmarks
Labels
Select theme
and set style to the map.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answer.